# Is there a content management system that fits these requirements or am I stuck rolling my own?

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm looking for some advice.

My boss is writing a series of lengthy articles. He wants to publish these articles on the web, but is reluctant to use anything other than MS Word for writing. However, he wants the web version of the article to include a lot of custom Javascript content (tooltips, links that pop up modal windows, and the like.) He also wants to be able to modify the articles after they've been published, to add new content, quotations, and the like.

So far, I've been able to convert one of his articles to html using Word, clean up Word's rotten HTML (using jQuery to filter or convert

tags to  tags, for example, or remove useless s), add the custom Javascript, and upload the whole thing to the server.

This works, but is very time-consuming, and leaves the paper in a state that is difficult for him to edit. It tends to fall to me to integrate the changes he makes into the HTML version of the article.

Ideally, what I would like is a CMS with the following features:

- The ability to create a document from a .doc or .docx file (not necessary, but would be great.)
- An easy to use WYSIWYG interface for editing, so he can edit the content of articles himself.
- The ability to easily throw in custom JavaScript, or even custom PHP code, to add the modals, and other functionality my boss likes.
- The ability to export documents back into .doc or .docx, or at least pdf format.

Oh, and it would be nice if the CMS could handle things like footnotes/endnotes, because there are a ton of them.

I've looked into [Silva](http://infrae.com/products/silva) and [Textpattern](http://textpattern.com/) so far. Textpattern uses Textile, which I think I can get my boss to use if necessary. Silva seemed very complicated, and perhaps overkill for what I am doing.

I COULD roll my own solution in PHP, using a framework like Yii, but this was only supposed to be a side-project and I would rather use something pre-made.

Does anyone have any recommendations? It doesn't have to be open-source. I think my employer would be willing to pay for a product if it could do all the things I mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Best of luck.  The best thing to do if you want such an interactive document is to let the web developer (you) do it.  Now, there's nothing wrong with your employer writing the articles (provided he knows how to properly write for web), as long as you strip all the formatting and add back in what is necessary later.  I've found the only useful tool for doing this to be Dreamweaver.  (In fact, it's the only reason I still keep a copy of Dreamweaver around.)

Comment: Is your boss likely to use a consistent set of javascript widgets/modal styles, or will they be invented and expanded ad hoc and ad nauseum?

Comment: Zero, I think Bootstrap provides all the interactivity he'd need. I used it for the first article and he seemed to really appreciate the minimalism of the default style.

Comment: Brad,

I'll look into Dreamweaver again. Used it years ago, but it's always seemed easier (until now) to hand-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good choice could be Wordpress. The way you've described it is really just getting content published that will be editable.

Wordpress also allows you to create custom themes or modify them. This would allow you to add the custom javascript or php that you desired. There are also a large selection of plugins that are easy to install and use.

Take a look at the features at http://wordpress.org.

UPDATE:

Two other choices you could look at are joomla and drupal. Both of them are content management systems.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. With a few WordPress plugins and custom [short codes] this could be the best solution.

Comment: +1, but I'm afraid most programmers don't like wordpress because it's a technical garbage, thus the downvotes.

Comment: I agree and I'm not a huge fan of Wordpress in most situations but Wordpress (or drupal, or joomla) seem like they would be a good choice for this.

Comment: I decided to go with Wordpress after all. I'd upvote if I had the reputation.

Comment: you can always click the check mark, that will help you get the rep

Answer (score 0):

Try convincing your boss to write the documents directly into a web-based wysiwyg system like http://wikiwig.sourceforge.net/. There is no point into duplicating all that content and the additional effort put into all that.